# button and div with same size is not equal in em while in px is equal

Tags: html, css

I defined a button and a div and their size once with unit of measurment px and again with em.
why when i defined their size by px ,div and button is equal but when i defined their size by
em button is smaller than div?

```css
   .div1 {
       width: 102px;
       height: 102px;
       border: 1px solid blue;
  }
    .button1{
       width: 102px;
       height: 102px;  
       border: 1px solid red;
  }
    .div2 {
       width: 10em;
       height: 10em;
       border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    .button2{
       width: 10em;
       height: 10em;  
       border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="div1"></div> 
 <button class="button1"></button>

 <div class="div2"></div> 
 <button class="button2"></button>
```

Comment: FWIW your div and button are *not* equal in size when defined with `px` values.

Answer (score 0):

`em` is based on the `font-size` and a button has a default `font-size` applied by the browser equal to `13px` so the button will have a size equal to `130px` and the div a size equal to `160px` since the default `font-size` for the document is `16px`

Change the font-size of the button and they will have the same size:

```css
.div1 {
  width: 102px;
  height: 102px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.button1 {
  width: 102px;
  height: 102px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.div2 {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.button2 {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<button class="button1"></button>

<div class="div2"></div>
<button class="button2"></button>
```

[image]

Comment: Good point. Plus, if you are using anything like Bootstrap, Material or jQuery UI (and who-knows-what-else), you have to take into consideration that other default values for button font sizes and padding could get applied. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Pixels (px) are a fixed size unit, unlike ems that are relative to the element font-size. Your div and your button are probably a different font-size value, probably by default if you have not defined it somewhere.

If you explicitly set the font-size to be equal, they will both have the same size:

```css
.div1 {
  width: 102px;
  height: 102px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.button1 {
  width: 102px;
  height: 102px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.div2 {
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.button2 {
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<button class="button1"></button>

<div class="div2"></div>
<button class="button2"></button>
```